L2−conforming (discontinuous) vs integration points
Finite element discretization spaces
Full de Rham complex
The picture below taken from here, displays from left to right:

H1−conforming (continuous)
H(curl)−conforming (continuous tangential component)
H(div)−conforming (continuous normal component)
L2−conforming (discontinuous)

The picture also displays from top to bottom the increasing discretization order for the full de Rham complex.

Quesiton
L2−conforming (discontinuous) vs integration points
Is the right-hand side of picture above, i.e. L2−conforming (discontinuous), actually showing the equivalent of the integration points discussed on some FEA documentation:



6.2.2 Eight-node brick element with reduced integration (C3D8R)


The C3D8R element is a general purpose linear brick element, with reduced inte-gration (1 integration point). The shape functions are the same as for the C3D8 element and can be found in [46]. The node numbering follows the convention of Figure 57 and the integration point is shown in Fig 59.


Due to the reduced integration, the locking phenomena observed in the C3D8 element do not show. However, the element exhibits other shortcomings:


• The element tends to be not stiff enough in bending.


• Stresses, strains.. are most accurate in the integration points. The integra-tion point of the C3D8R element is located in the middle of the element. Thus, small elements are required to capture a stress concentration at the boundary of a structure.


I realized that these are two different concepts:

L2−conforming (discontinuous) basis functions
Integration points


The L2 space relates to the type of function space used for the approximation, and the integration points relate to the numerical technique used to compute the integrals within the finite element method.

